# I would like to automate the ssh login to an AIX server that hs

Tags: ssh, expect

I would like to automate the login to an AIX server. I dont have a way to set up ssh keys im on mac so i cant install ssh pass so my only option left would be expect.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 20
spawn ssh name@host.com
expect "*: "
send "veryStrongPassword\r";
```

Issue with that is that nothing happens and i am thinking its because there is a new line above

```
Unauthorized use of this system is prohibited.
's password:
```

So my questiobn shoud i just add another expect on top with this line ?

What if i have several lines above the password ?

Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt that you can't create and use ssh keys on your Mac.

Comment: `ssh-keygen`, `ssh-copy-id`, `ssh-agent` and `ssh` all live in /usr/bin on my Mac.

Comment: its not i cant create ssh keys its that the AIX is an enterpirse box that wont just allow me to copy-paste ssh keys the only command there avilable is LS

Comment: and this is besides the point, i asked for something specific